# The "content" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I can't quite understand why we need a "content" tag, and looking at [the questions currently tagged as such](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content) doesn't really help. I think it should either be removed or we need to more clearly define what it stands for. Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's... rather vague. To understate it. The current questions are about:

- Content ratings (and thus, the content of the game itself)
- Removed content (and thus, the content of the game itself)
- Editable content (and thus, the content of the game itself)

This shared factor, "content of the game", is... I mean, what kind of questions about a game *aren't* about the content of that game?

It basically strikes me as the same kind of tag as [games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games) - it describes a default context of a question. The majority of questions about a particular game are going to be about that game, by definition, and so they are about its content. The minority is questions that aren't about the actual content, which is things like advertising.

There could be arguments made for specific tags of other portions (like all three above-mentioned stuff, though I don't know that we have all that much need for any particular one), but I don't think the general tag is remotely useful.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Comment: **Fire** - apply directly to forehead.